# How to send a key event to an NSTextField that does not have focus in swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, nstextfield

I have a view that contains an NSTableView and an NSTextField. The table view has focus. I would like to use the text field as a filter for the table view. Is there any way that I can send a key press event, which is captured by the table view, to the NSTextField?

Here is the keyDown func as I have it, I would like to send theEvent to the text field in the default handler of the switch statement.

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let s   =   theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers!
    let s1  =   s.unicodeScalars
    let s2  =   s1[s1.startIndex].value
    let s3  =   Int(s2)
    switch s3 {
        case NSUpArrowFunctionKey:
            self.previous()
            return
        case NSDownArrowFunctionKey:
            self.next()
            return
        default:
            // this appends the text to the textField, Is there a way to send theEvent to the textField?
            textField.stringValue = textField.stringValue + s;

            // textField.keyDown(theEvent) // this does not work
            break
    }
}
```

I would like to not have to force the user to change focus to the text field in order to filter the table view results.

Comment: Text fields do not process key events. When they have focus, a separate text view is added to the window that overlaps the text field. That text view, known as the [field editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html), processes key events and other things (e.g. Edit menu items). The text field does not. So, when a text field does not have focus, there's nothing to handle such events. The Mac UI convention is to use a separate `NSSearchField` and do type-to-select in the table.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I decided to leave the NSTextField as the firstResponder and handle the events I wanted in the NSTextFieldDelegate control function using doCommandBySelector.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it the `-keyDown:` is sent to the `firstResponder` which in this case is the table view.

I don't like this idea and I would implement this is a different way, but you could try inserting the text field into the responder chain and a position above table view. You would have to subclass the text field and implement `mouseDown` to capture the events and you would also have to change you table views mouse down implementation so it didn't capture the event for the text field. This is overly complicated.

**Why not simply set the target/action of the text field and deal with user input outside of the event loop?**